# Change landing page if user visited a certain page first in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have fairly big landing page with lots of editable text fields.

However if the user visits the landing page from one certain page, I don't want the text fields pages to be editable.

I thought there must be a better way than creating the same landing page twice just without editable text fields on one of them. This is the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: hello, please consider sharing relevant sample of your code

Comment: You can evaluate the referrer header in the request, sure, but that is not reliable and only works if that other request was the one before. Otherwise you need to implement sessions.

Comment: Try "document.referrer" to see previous url. If user clicked any link to visit your page it should be filled. Then you can decide to disable fields with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cookies to determine whether someone has been on a page, either ever or over a long period of time, or you can use Session to determine whether they have visited the page in this browsing session.

Cookies are most likely what you are looking for in your given example.

[PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

An example :

```
// Set the cookie on the page you wish to check if they've visited
setcookie("pageVisited", yes, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

Then on the landing page, we check for the cookie.

```
// Checks if the cookie is present.
if(isset($_COOKIE['pageVisited'])){
//Display content without text fields
} else{
//Display content WITH text fields
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I never worked with cookies, but that makes sense for sure. I have to wait a few minutes before I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Frederic Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

will give you the referrer page's URL. get the filename from URL and add the condition to show fields.